# Float left somehow being broken

Tags: html, css, css-float

Take a look at http://new.reyniersaudio.com/test.html

The idea here is that I want the container "modelInfoRightCol" to wrap around "modelInfoRightCol (the picture of the case and pricing info)".

What am I doing that's preventing this from happening.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're HTML is pretty broken. You have elements using a common ID and some other markup problems (I ignore attributes and entity references).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "elements using a common ID" ... forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The containing div has no assigned width so it's just wide enough (with `overflow: hidden`) to contain the inner divs, the widest div in this case. If you want to make it wider, give it an explicit width.

This is one way of fixing the problem:

```
#modelInfoLeftCol { width: 600px; }
```

Comment: The problem is that once I assign a width #modelInfoLeftCol it will show the two divs side by side... is there any way i could have the LeftCol wrap around the RightCol?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Not sure I understand.

Comment: Hehe, I'll try to be more clear.  So, I added the width value, which works fine except I'd like for the content in the LeftCol to wrap around the RightCol.  FE: The information "Our Quad Core Workstations are fully tested with...." would extend underneath the RightCol all the way to 800px.  Maybe this is impossible.

Comment: If modelInfoRightCol was within the tab content you could do it. Since it's outside (I guess so it's visible no matter which tab you select), it makes it difficult (if not impossible).

Comment: I'm experimenting with putting the RightCol inside the LeftCol, but like you guessed that tabs break it.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a width to `#modelInfoLeftCol`.